# Cordova - Refused to connect to api from device (Content Security Policy)

Tags: node.js, cordova, visual-studio-cordova, content-security-policy

I am working with Visual Studio's Tools for Apache Cordova.

When I build the app with Ripple, all is well. But when I build it to my android device, the app refuses to connect to my external API.

This is the error in the JavaScript Console log:

> Refused to connect to 'http://XXX.herokuapp.com/api/posts/0/5' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'".
>
> Note that 'connect-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is
>   used as a fallback.

And:

> Error: Failed to execute 'open' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Refused to
>   connect to 'http:// XXX. herokuapp. com/api/posts/0/5'

My API is built with Node.js and express. There is Access-Control-Allow-Headers in my server.js, but it still doesn't work on my device.

**Server.js:**

```
//'use strict';

var express    = require('express');        // call express
var app        = express();                 // define our app using express
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var methodOverride = require('method-override');
var router = express.Router();
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

app.use(bodyParser.json()); // parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/vnd.api+json' })); // parse application/vnd.api+json as json
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(methodOverride('X-HTTP-Method-Override')); // override with the X-HTTP-Method-Override header in the request. simulate DELETE/PUT

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/www')); 

// middleware to use for all requests

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    console.log('in middleware');

    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');//allowing ripple's localhost get access to node's localhost(5432).
    console.log(req.header);
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers',"X-Requested-With,Content-Type");
    //res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    // Pass to next layer of middleware
    next();
});


require('./app/routes')(app); // pass our application into our routes -- must
app.use('/api', router);//put this line beofre passing app to routes.js for it to take effect.

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(port, function() {
  console.log("Listening on " + port);
});

exports = module.exports = app;   // expose app
```

I have also tried adding a meta tag to my index.html file, but with no success.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' http://localhost:8080 http://XXX.herokuapp.com">
```

Any ideas what might be the problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the Error Message. You are calling Ajax Request in your JS. But you only added `http://XXX.herokuapp.com` after `script-src`, which only allows loading the script content. To allow the Ajax request, `http://XXX.herokuapp.com` needs to be added after `connect-src`like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; connect-src 'self' http://XXX.herokuapp.com; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
```

Alternatively, you can add the URL after `default-src`, which sets a default policy for allowing everything(loading script/CSS contents,Ajax Request and so on). So the meta Tag should be like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' http://XXX.herokuapp.com data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
```

For detailed information about Content Security Policy you can refer to [Content Security Policy Reference](http://content-security-policy.com/).