# Cordova security policy while trying to get json data from api

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api, cordova

```
jquery-1.11.1.min.js:4 Refused to connect to 
'https://xxxxxxxx/v1/common/introductions/faqs' because it 
violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 
'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'". Note that 
'connect-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a 
 fallback.
```

This is the error i am getting while executing this jquery for my cordova app

```
$(document).ready(function(){


        $("#FAQS").html("Hello worldss!");
        alert("rajesh");
        $.getJSON("https://xxxxxxxxx/v1/common/introductions/faqs",
        function(result)
        {
            $("#FAQS").html(result['faq'][0]);
            alert("hi");
        })

   });
```

Here is my security policy in my index.html

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' 
data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; connect-src 'self' 
https://xxxxxxxx/v1/common/introductions/faqs; style-src 'self' 
'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
```

I followed many questions in stack overflow 
[Cordova - Refused to connect to api from device (Content Security Policy)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38284317/cordova-refused-to-connect-to-api-from-device-content-security-policy)

but could not display my json data and it is showing the same error

Comment: can you check with `https://xxxxxxxx` only?

Comment: @shakib Yep using `connect-src 'self' https://xxxxxxxx;` should do the job

Comment: @shakib the api is working

Comment: So did shakibs proposal work for you?

Comment: You are waiting for deviceready right?

Answer (score 3):

Check out the following [example from html5rocks](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/content-security-policy/#source-whitelists):

If you wanted to whitelist code from `https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js` you'd have to add the source host's name to your CSP like so

```
script-src 'self' https://apis.google.com
```

So to allow access to `https://xxxxxxxx/v1/common/introductions/faqs` you'll have to add the corresponding host's name to your CSP:

```
connect-src 'self' https://xxxxxxxx
```

A complete CSP could look like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' 
data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; connect-src 'self' 
https://xxxxxxxx; style-src 'self' 
'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
```

Also see [Mozilla's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/connect-src) on the connect-src directive. It explicitly states how the host-source has to look like:

> Internet hosts by name or IP address, as well as an optional URL scheme and/or port number. The site's address may include an optional
>   leading wildcard (the asterisk character, '*'), and you may use a
>   wildcard (again, '*') as the port number, indicating that all legal
>   ports are valid for the source.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should use a more recent version of jquery.

Second, you need to set the access policy on the server to allow CORS from your UI...

in php it looks like this:

```
<?php
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

you can find out how to do it in other languages here: https://enable-cors.org

Third. are you using nginx as your web server or as a reverse proxy? If it's the latter, you're going to need to check your nginx xconfig.

Comment: CSP and CORS are different things. CSP limits what your page is allowed to do and where it can load content from (header constrains outbound requests). CORS limits which pages can make certain types of requests to your site (header constrains inbound requests - XMLHttpRequest, web fonts, WebGL textures and canvas images).